# Counting/Summing marked cells

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Spreadsheet where I want Friday and Sunday totals per row for cells that are check-marked in Friday and Sunday cells.

For example:

[image]

How do I create a formula for that?

Thanks,

Brandon

Comment: what is the hex number for your checkmark?

Comment: It's a Wingding ü

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

**To get your total checkmarks for Friday, use:**

`=SUMPRODUCT(--((WEEKDAY($D$2:$M$2,1)=6))*--(($D3:$M3="ü")))`

<sup>(replace `$D$2:$M$2` with your range of dates, and `$D3:$M3` with the cells holding your checks and x's for that row)</sup>

**To get your total checkmarks for Sunday, use:**

`=SUMPRODUCT(--((WEEKDAY($D$2:$M$2,1)=1))*--(($D3:$M3="ü")))`

<sup>(again making the same replacements as above)</sup>

As a side recommendation, I would use Wingdings 2, character "P" for a checkmark and character "O" (capital O) for an x. They're just easier and more familiar characters to work with.

Comment: TotsieMae, your solution worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for your posting!  I upvoted your solution, but my account reputation is not high enough to display it.  Thanks again.